# Reporting progress on a WPF background worker running a WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am working on an application which consists of two components, a client application and a WCF service.  One of the methods I need to call in my service is a long-running process and I don't want to tie up the WPF UI whilst it is running and I'd also like to report progress as each stage completes.  I've created a background worker as follows:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);

// run the process
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The DoWork looks like follows (proxy is my connection to the service):

```
proxy.CopyProjectToProduction(selectedItem, localDir, currentLabel);
```

This method is a 6-stage process, some of which can take milliseconds and some of which can take 10 seconds or more.  What I want my WPF progress bar to be able to do is to report on each of these stages and then inform the service it has updated.  The service needs to halt after each item has completed and wait until it receives confirmation from the UI that it has completed.  To try and do this I first created the following type:

```
[DataContract]
public enum CopyProgress
{

    [EnumMember]
    Waiting = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    ConnectedToDev = 1,

   // other enumerated types
}
```

Within the service I have three methods.  Two publically accessible ones, which get the enumerated value and reset it and another private one which is called by the service and is as follows:

```
 public void WaitForStatusReset()
 {
     while (progress != CopyProgress.Waiting) { }
 }
```

An example of part of my service code for the long-running process is as follows:

```
// establish a connection to dev and update progress
CreateTfsConnection(cDevServer);
progress = CopyProgress.ConnectedToDev;

WaitForStatusReset();
```

This is repeated for each of the 6 items in the service.  The idea being that it will complete it's work to the correct enumerated type and then wait for the UI to complete.  The UI does the following (inside a larger loop):

```
CopyProgress currentProgress = proxy.GetCopyStatus();

// if the progress has changed then we need to increment the progress bar
if (currentProgress != CopyProgress.Finished && currentProgress != progress)
{
    worker.ReportProgress((int)progressIncrement);
    proxy.ResetCopyStatus();
}
```

This *should* loop constantly looking for a change in the progress variable and when it determines that it has changed, it will update the progress bar and then reset the service.  The service will then see it has been set back to Waiting and continue with the next bit.  In practice the currentProgress variable is set once (to Waiting) and then the next iteration of the loop the program hangs.  I suspect I am getting into some kind of deadlock situation here, but I can't work out where I am going wrong.

I could change my service so each part of the process is exposed as a method, but I'd like avoid this if possible, as I want to try and keep the client coding as light as possible and do everything in the service.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Give us something for us to be able replicate the issue on our machines.

Comment: which type of binding you are using  wshttpbinding or httpbinding or what ?

Comment: @Julie, it's wsHttpBinding.  I don't think the problems with the service as I have another async method that does a far simpler process and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of blocking the service to wait for call from the UI is. Also unless this is a single-threaded single instance WCF service maintaining the state of the operation within the service is going to cause headaches.

You would be better served by writing the status of the operation out to a message queue or database table which the UI can listen to or poll. If you really want to maintain status state within the service you'll need a dictionary to map progress to a particular call.

Comment: The blocking is because it's possible more than 1 item might complete in the service before my client detects it which means the progress bar will be incorrect.  I like the queue idea though.  I'll give it a try and get back to you.  Thanks.